# Owl Carousel and bootstrap width displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I actually have an example of this problem.
If you click the link you will see half way down the page featured offers.
These offers are displaying completely incorrectly.
They are supposed to be full width mobile and then col-sm-3 for all other devices.

[www.exclusivecard.co.uk](http://www.exclusivecard.co.uk)

this only happened since I added owl carousel to them.  I will post the code below anyway.

**styles**

```
 #offerslide .owlItem{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
 }
```

**page**

```
 <div class="owlslide">
      <a href="somelink">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 owlItem">

      <div class="row" id="yellow">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
          <div class="panel panel-warning coupon">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="head">
              <div class="panel-title" id="title">

                <span >title</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">                

             <img>
              <div class="col-md-12 text-warning">
                <div class="offer">
                  <span class="number">[saving]</span>                     
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer" id="coupon-backing">
              <div class="coupon-code">
                [cat]
                <span class="print">
               [expires]
                </span>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</a>
 </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#owlslide").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
    items : 3,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,2],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
 });
```

Comment: Instead of `col-xs-12` do `col-md-12` in `owlItem` class.

Comment: @SujataChanda  Why did that work?  Can you please add it as a proper answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Personally I would remove `col-sm-3` from the `owlitem` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `col-xs-12` to `col-md-12` in owlItem class as `col-xs-12` is an extra small class and md/lg is used for desktop representations.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of this `col-xs-12 col-sm-3 owlItem`,  so bootstrap is creating column of 25% width inside `owl-item` that is created by owl Carousel like this.

```
element.style {
  width: 464px;
}
```

You should remove `col-xs-12 col-sm-3` and set widths of your items with owl carousel.